# using fixed contain-to-grid in nav wrapper adds extra height

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

using Foundation 4, i decided to make the nav bar of my site sticky.  following some examples i found, i wrapped my  section in a  and gave it the classes "fixed" and "contain-to-grid".  the fixed tag results in adding bottom padding to the nav bar equal to what the margin is supposed to be.  when i use chrome, or firefox inspectors i cannot find the css responsible for doing this.  i have added a new line to css to set a max height.  doing this wound up removing the margin that was used to offset the body content.  i feel like i shouldn't have to add this new css rule.  has anyone experienced this, and how did you fix it?

```
<div class="contain-to-grid fixed">
    <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <!-- Title Area -->
            <li class="name">
                <h1><a href="/" style="background-image: url(/Content/logos/logo_color_105x35.png); text-indent: -119988px; width: 105px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%;">company</a></h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <!-- Left Nav Section -->

            <!-- Right Nav Section -->
            <ul class="right">
                <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "RegisterLink" })</li>
                <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign in", "SignIn", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "SignInLink" })</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

new css rule i added
    .contain-to-grid.fixed{
        max-height:45px;
    }

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Emh8P/6/

Comment: post a code or a fiddle

Comment: hard to understand from the given source

Answer (score 1):

I took your html and threw it into a js bin.

It looks like the CSS responsible is a margin-bottom on the top-bar element. `<nav class="top-bar">`

If you were to put the fixed class on the nav instead of your contain class it fixes it to the top of the page without any issue that I could see.

```
<div class="contain-to-grid">
    <nav class="top-bar fixed">
```

Here is a jsbin that I put the fixed on the top bar rather than the contain-to-grid. http://jsbin.com/ehekEBE/1/

If that does not work for you, you just need to get rid of the `margin-bottom:1.875em` that is tied to the top bar.

## Revision

After looking at the new jsfiddle that you posted I looked a little more into the behavior you are seeing. When you open the menu for the nav what Foundation is doing is it is moving the fixed class from the parent element to the child element. When this happens the position of the nav itself loses its stickiness because it is no longer fixed, also the margin associated with the inner section of the nav is being rendered.

If you make your nav have both `position:fixed !important;` and `top:0 !important;` then it will stay fixed at the top of the screen and will not change margin in any visible fashion.

Hope that helps.

http://jsbin.com/IGArABO/2/

Comment: i will try rearranging my css tags

Comment: unchecking answer.  this seems to work for F3, but not for F4

Comment: @Michael I think you should look again, the jsbin was using foundation 4.  This is from the jsbin imports. 4.1.6/css/foundation.min.css

Comment: so, i pulled down a fresh css file from zurb just to make sure.  and you are correct. placing fixed in the <nav> does work.  however, this does not make it stick to the top as the documentation says it should.

Comment: Can you throw up a jsbin with what you have so I can look?

Comment: i added a fiddle to my original post

Comment: @Michael, just added a revision per your jsfiddle.  I also switched it to JSBin, you might want to use JSBin in the future since it has an import for Foundation and you do not have to copy and paste so much css and js.  Alternatively if there is a reason you absolutely have to use jsfiddle, you can use the same CDN to include foundation that JSBin uses see this fiddle where I did the imports for you, its on the left in external resources. http://jsfiddle.net/Emh8P/8/

Comment: good to know.  i was having trouble finding the cdn for foundation so i just copy/pastad

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Emh8P/10/ by implementing your fix, the body content now works its way up behind the top bar.

Comment: it also seem to break the auto-spacing and width

Comment: @Michael, this is because when you have something like the nav being fixed it is not in the normal DOM flow, you will need to have padding or margin at the top of a div wrapping the main part of your content.

Comment: that breaks the whole idea of having a css framework that handles this for me.

Comment: Michael, I understand your frustration, maybe you could open an issue on the github for foundation and use this thread as a reference. However the question is answered does it resolve your immediate issue? https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues?state=open

Comment: it does not resolve the issue better than what i am already doing.   it appears this is a known issue after browsing the open foundation bugs. https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3134

Comment: Hope it gets fixed soon.  Good luck.